# netbeans (or PHP in general) debugging options

Tags: php, xdebug

I have tried for months (quite possibly years in toto) to get xdebug to work with Netbeans with no success... I have to have debugging! Is there an alternative?

What are my options (without porting everything to Zend server)
Am I doomed to crawl back to M$ and become a .NET developer once more?

Comment: Yes, there are several alternatives. Really quick Google search revealed this: https://jtreminio.com/2012/07/xdebug-and-you-why-you-should-be-using-a-real-debugger/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ - I never managed to make Netbeans work with xdebug, but with PHPStorm it worked the first time.

Comment: holy sh@t, Batman! I used it for like 5 minutes and I am thinking about buying it... Thanks for the advice.